# Error 'there is no package called 'rio'' when using fviz_dend and fviz_cluster

Tags: r, r-rio

I'm running an ACP on a dataset and when I tried to use fviz_dend or fviz_cluster on the hcpc result it returns this error:

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
> vI[[i]]): there is no package called 'rio'

Libraries FactoMineR and factoextra are loaded, ggplot2 as well.

I tried to install rio package but I had another error:

> Warning message: "dependency 'foreign' is not available"
>
> There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
> binary source needs_compilation rio 0.5.26 0.5.27             FALSE
>
> installing the source package 'rio'
>
> Warning message in install.packages("rio"): "installation of package
> 'rio' had non-zero exit status"

After that when I try to `install library('rio')` it returns an error :

> there is no package called 'rio'

I've read the fviz_dend documentation and it never mention any rio.

What can I do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `rio` is a dependency of both `FactoMineR` and `factoextra`. You can see if this by running the following line.

```
library(packrat)

packrat:::recursivePackageDependencies("FactoMineR",lib.loc = .libPaths()[1])
#[79] "purrr"   "quantreg"   "readr"   "readxl"  "rematch"   "rio"
```

The error might be dependent on your operating system, so probably need to see the full error message. You may not have the proper tools (like `cmake`, which you would need to install on your command line) installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Thanck you for your help :)

I was using a jupyter notebook, now I've transfered my work on R studio and there is no more issue. I think it was linked to the operating system as you said.